# How do I close all open tabs at once?

Tags: vim, vi, shortcut

If I have 10 tabs opened, I have to close each one using ":q" separately.

How can I close them all at once?

Answer (score 665, accepted):

Shortest/simplest/fastest way would be:

```
:qa
```

To save work in all tabs and quit:

```
:wqa
```

Comment: :wqa can be simplified to just :xa

Comment: Never use `:x` never never never. You'll screw up some day and do `:X` encrypt your file, and you won't know the key.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin I use :x all the time, and have never accidentally encrypted a file.

Comment: @Singlestone Good for you? I think the upvotes show that you maybe the exception.

Comment: Good for me indeed! I may be the exception. I am at least a data point. Never say "never never never", that's my motto. :)

Comment: @dhblah :q! is most definitely not the same as :qa!  Open two buffers, make unsaved changes in both, then try using :q!  You will be sent back and forth between them until you finally use :qa!

Comment: @AaronMcMillin: I know this is an old question, but at least on my current Vim, you would have to (1) type uppercase `X` (2) accidentally enter a password, (3) accidentally enter the *same* password again, before this would be a problem. I don't see that as very likely...

Comment: @jwd That's good to know. I've been vim'ing for a long time. and I know I have encrypted files and not been able to open them because of not following was happened after :X

Comment: Maybe remap X away from encrypt so it can never happen again (at least from one character :)?

Comment: I noticed nobody said anything about using `ZZ` or `ZQ` which are the same as `:x` and `:q!`. If you're afraid of using `:x` because it's similar to `:X` then maybe give `ZZ` a go. That's my goto command for write and quit. Doesn't really answer the original question, but adds to this conversation.

Comment: @Aaron Whereas your advice is of the highest value, if someone blind-types then `x` is pressed always with a ring finger and natural holding of `Shift` (for `:` purpose) involves a pinky finger which is clearly pulled off the `Shift` while pressing `x` making it almost impossible to press `Shift+x` with respectively your pinky finger AND your ring finger unintentionally :) Anyway the advice is still worth obeying.

Answer (score 235):

I often use **`:tabo`** (`:tabonly`) to close all other tabs.

Comment: “close all other tabs” is much faster achieved by “:on” (for “only”, i.e. “the only window to show”). :)

Comment: @Bombe: for me it didn't work, too. `:on` only closes *windows*, not tabs, at least in my vim 7.3.3.

Comment: `:tabo` is _exactly_ what I was looking for. I'd upvote you 30 times if I could. :)

Comment: This has a side benefit that it still keeps all the tabs in the buffer list. You can see them with `:ls`. So you can still recover the tabs later if you want. Or convert them to windows, etc.

Comment: @JustinForce [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1223578/988483) from "close all tabs to the right" at SuperUser might be worth a look. I mapped it to a shortcut key and it has replaced my usage `:tabo`.

Answer (score 29):

That can be done with the following
 command (in normal or escape mode):

> ```
> :tabdo :q
> ```

"tabdo" apparently executes the
command for all the open tabs.

Comment: Note, this isn't my answer.  I moved this out of the original non-question down to here.

Answer (score 24):

You can use any of these Vim *Ex commands* to **Exit Multiple Windows And Buffers**:

1. `:qa` `:qall`

   Exit Vim, unless there are some buffers which have been changed.  (Use `:bmod` to go to the next modified buffer). When 'autowriteall' is set all changed buffers will be written, like `:wqall`.
2. `:conf qa` `:confirm qall`

   Exit Vim.  Bring up a prompt when some buffers have been 
               changed.  See `:confirm`.
3. `:qa!` `:qall!`

   Exit Vim.  Any changes to buffers are lost. Also see `:cquit`, it does the same but exits with a non-zero value.
4. `:quita` `:quitall` `:quita!` `:quitall!`

   Same as `:qall`.
5. `:wqa` `:wqall` `:xa` `:xall`

   Write all changed buffers and exit Vim.  If there are buffers
               without a file name, which are readonly or which cannot be
               written for another reason, Vim will not quit.
6. `:conf wqa` `:confirm wqall` `:conf xa` `:confirm xall`

   Write all changed buffers and exit Vim.  Bring up a prompt
               when some buffers are readonly or cannot be written for
               another reason.  See `:confirm`.
7. `:wqa!` `:xa!` `:wqall!` `:xall!`

   Write all changed buffers, even the ones that are readonly,
               and exit Vim.  If there are buffers without a file name or
               which cannot be written for another reason, Vim will not quit.

To read about these in Vim, type the following Ex command

```
:help window-exit
```

Answer (score 19):

Adding to what fuentesjr said:

```
:qa!
```

Will force quit all tabs, if you don't care about saving.

Answer (score 7):

```
:qall
```

This closes all tabs and open buffers.

Answer (score 1):

here is an Dark Side way of closing ALL VIM INSTANCES on Linux/Mac

```
:!killall vim -9
```

Do not use it. It does what you ask but probably not the best way but fun way

Comment: You may close other people's sessions if you accidentally happen to be root. Not very funny :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the VIM plugin in VSCode and I was looking for a way to close all the tabs open on the current window.

The commands `:qa` and `:wqa` didn't work because they closed all the tabs from all the windows.

The command `:tabonly` closed all the tabs from the current window except the current tab.

Because I'm usually only using 2 windows at the same time, the closer I managed to get to my need was to focus on the other window and run the command :

```
:on
```

(`:only`) it closes all the windows except the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I use the VSvim extension for Visual Studio 2019, if this is helpful for others:

- `:qa` quits Visual Studio entirely
- `:tabo` closes all tabs except the open one
- `:bd` parse error
- `:tabclose` / `:tabc` parse error

  Tab commands like `:tabn` and `:tabp` do work.