# vim: how to quit vim when I split window?

Tags: vim

I have to type :q many times if I split window (or open file in a new tab) in vim to close every splited window( or tabs). Is there any way to exit vim just type one time :q and save all changes?

Comment: Same as for tabs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510325/how-do-i-close-all-open-tabs-in-vim-at-once

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To save and quit all. This is what you need.

```
:wqa
```

Note that the following will do the same thing because `:xa` is a synonym for `:wqa`. This is my favourite since it is shorter to type.

```
:xa
```

To quit all:

```
:qa
```

To not save (lose changes) and quit all:

```
:qa!
```

Comment: This is such a common task that I find very useful to have a specific mapping for it: `nnoremap <silent> ZZ :qall<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

```
:qa
:wqa
```

Mnemonic: *write quit all*. You can access the docs like this from within Vim:

```
:help :quit
```

Answer (score 0):

`:x` is a shorthand for `:wq` so `:xa` saves and closes everything.